# Add a UITabbarControler in UIScrollView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I have made a UIScrollView inside a UIViewController .and now I want to add a UITabBarController to it .But when I do it ,I couldnot see the TabBarController added to it..

I have written this code

```
[testscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[testscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,800)];
FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
first.title=@"Search";
UserProfile *second=[[UserProfile alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserProfile" bundle:nil];
second.title=@"My Profile";

UserActivities *third=[[UserActivities alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserActivities" bundle:nil];
third.title=@"My Activities";
LogOut *logout=[[LogOut alloc]initWithNibName:@"LogOut" bundle:nil];
logout.title=@"Sign Out";
NSArray *viewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second,third,logout, nil];
tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

I have added this in  a fifthViewController.I can see the UIScrollView and some Labels and textFields added but not the TabBarController added.Wher i m going wrong ..?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are creating a tab bar controller and then presenting it modally:

```
NSArray *viewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second,third,logout, nil];
tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

It does not appear in `scrollView` because you are not "connecting" the two in any ways.

If you want your tab bar controller to appear inside of the scroll view, add it as a subview to the latter:

```
[testscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[testscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,800)];
...
[testscroll addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

(I assume that `tabBarController` is a property and that the scroll view is displayed in some way)

Comment: Actually I tried ut ur code and here firsttabbar item  is set as default and all the content of FirstViewController is being displayed on the fifthViewController.What I want is I just want a TabBarController added at the bottom of FifthViewController with four tabbar items and no tabbar item selected as default  because FifthtabViewController contains some content in it .

Comment: what you see is how you defined your tabbar. it contains 4 controllers: first,second,third,logout. i don't know anything about your FifthtabViewController, since you do not show anything of it, but if you want it to be displayed in the tab bar, you better add it to the tab bar controller like the other controllers. From your comment, it seems you are trying to use a tab bar controller thinking of it as if it were a `UITabBar`.

Comment: I have FifthViewController(AppntmntSuccess) with some data on it.I  want to display a tabbar (Search,Profile,Activities,SignOut)added at the bottom to that viewController and no tabBaritem should be selected as default.In my case what is happening is  first tabbaritem is selected as default so all the content of it (FirstViewController) is displayed or overlapped with the content of FifthViewController.How can I make a TabBarController with such that no tabbar item is selected as default..?

Comment: you might try to make *all* the controllers within your tab bar controllers transparent (their views, I mean), so that you can see what is behind them. but this would be a pretty strange use of UITabBarController. possibly what you are looking for is adding a `UITabBar` to your FifthViewController and then manage its events.

Comment: K following ur comment I have added a UITabBar through interface builder and set its delegate to View .But I couldnot see  it added .Can u please tell me y ?